# K8s Port forward into network namespace - Connection Refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes, open-telemetry

I'm running into an issue while hosting Open Telemetry Collector on K8s. We are using [open telemetry helm-charts](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/tree/main/charts/opentelemetry-collector) to deploy in an OKE cluster. The deployment succeeds however, the port-forward to the pod fails with the following error:

```
E0607 13:04:55.415015 48206 portforward.go:407] an error occurred forwarding 55679 -> 55679: 
error forwarding port 55679 to pod 0f6ea4c9367d6748039fd42da1b7c08c43f1d442859aff087c0c061a0a27d6ff, uid : port forward into network namespace "/var/run/netns/483d52c1-0107-4dbc-9153-d47a6bc64779": failed to connect to localhost:55679 inside namespace 0f6ea4c9367d6748039fd42da1b7c08c43f1d442859aff087c0c061a0a27d6ff: dial tcp [::1]:55679: connect: connection refused
E0607 13:04:55.416590   48206 portforward.go:233] lost connection to pod
```

The pods has other ports exposed like 4318 as well and port-forwarding to that port works as expected. Open-Telemetry in [v0.47.0 release](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/blob/main/charts/opentelemetry-collector/UPGRADING.md#0460-to-0470), changed IP from 0.0.0.0 to POD_IP which prevented port-forwarding. I reverted the change back to 0.0.0.0, after which 4318 started working, however still run into this issue with port 55679.

Here's how my pod specification looks like:

```
Name:             otel-opentelemetry-collector-65cc995479-rkz97
Namespace:        monitoring
Priority:         0
Service Account:  opentelemetry-collector
Node:             10.36.92.85/10.36.92.85
Start Time:       Wed, 07 Jun 2023 12:54:17 +0530
Labels:           app=opentelemetry-collector
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=otel
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=opentelemetry-collector
                  component=standalone-collector
                  environment=test
                  pod-template-hash=65cc995479
Annotations:      checksum/config: 622eb05ba3357fc2b4a4e4dc4afa8e1da114f69335daaadd932c4f906f073941
Status:           Running
IP:               100.64.0.124
IPs:
  IP:           100.64.0.124
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/otel-opentelemetry-collector-65cc995479
Containers:
  opentelemetry-collector:
    Container ID:  cri-o://e5ea6e6b499d0a036d5e5a073b78b2f3df416440c6ae767c48f7f0612d5c8102
    Image:         otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib@sha256:42e8ba40f9f70d604684c3a2a0ed321206b7e2e3509fdb2c8836d34f2edfb57b
    Image ID:      docker.io/otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib@sha256:2746e53e8f510d5c2f30a8c805c904e9d22257fd9bec4ddfed2776d55fabeb06
    Ports:         8006/TCP, 8889/TCP, 4317/TCP, 4318/TCP, 55679/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /otelcol-contrib
      --config=/conf/relay.yaml
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 07 Jun 2023 12:54:18 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:13133/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:13133/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MY_POD_IP:   (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /conf from opentelemetry-collector-configmap (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rvkhs (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  opentelemetry-collector-configmap:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      otel-opentelemetry-collector
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-rvkhs:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m34s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned monitoring/otel-opentelemetry-collector-65cc995479-rkz97 to 10.36.92.85
  Normal   Pulled     2m34s  kubelet            Container image "otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib@sha256:42e8ba40f9f70d604684c3a2a0ed321206b7e2e3509fdb2c8836d34f2edfb57b" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m34s  kubelet            Created container opentelemetry-collector
  Normal   Started    2m34s  kubelet            Started container opentelemetry-collector
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m34s  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://100.64.0.124:13133/": dial tcp 100.64.0.124:13133: connect: connection refused
```

I have been stuck with this since last 3 days, so appreciate any help or direction to proceed further

**Updates**

1. I tried cURL from my localhost to port 4318 on the pod. It works
2. I run a service inside a docker container on my MAC and use host.docker.internal on the 4318 port on my host machine. It errors out with the similar error as above.
3. Tried adding --address 0.0.0.0 while port-forwarding. That doesn't help either

Gist is that cURL from localhost on my MAC works whereas from inside a Docker container on MAC does not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was bombarded with lots of work. So, this issue resolved. Couple of things that I had to do: Ensure the K8s service exposes the relevant ports to connect to and run my docker-compose with network_mode set to host such that the network namespace used by the docker container and the MAC system was same

Answer (score 0):

The connection is refused because there is no process listening to port 55679. That port hasn't been exposed.

To get the port on which your pod is listening to, you can run the below commands:

1. To get the name of the pods in the specified namespace

   `kubectl get po -n <namespace>`
2. To check the exposed port of the pod you'll like to forward.

   `kubectl get pod <pod-name> -n <namespace> --template='{{(index (index  .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}'`

Now use the resulting exposed port above to run port-forward with the command:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/<pod-name><local-port>:<exposed-port>
```

where local-port is the port from which the container will be accessed from the browser. while the exposed-port is the port on which the container listens.

Refer to document on [Use port forwarding to access applications in a cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) for more information.

Comment: When I check the port exposed is only 8006. However, I'm able to port-forward to 4318, 8888 and 13133 without any issues.

Comment: Refer to this link on [Troubleshooting common port forwading issues](https://blog.noip.com/troubleshooting-common-port-forwarding-issues#:~:text=The%20first%20step%20in%20troubleshooting,forwarding%20rule%20is%20correctly%20configured.) .Let me know if this helps.